# Android LocationListener reports speeds of up to 10-15 m/s when not moving, near window indoors

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I am trying to create a program that will detect when the device is moving inside a motorvehicle. For this I register a LocationListener and use hasSpeed and getSpeed on the returned location.

However, when I am indoors just by the window, sometimes I see speeds going all over the place... 1, 2, 4, even 15 meters per second. When I reload the application the pattern seems to change (sometimes no fix at all so it doesn't say anything...etc)

I have tested the GPS using google maps. What I see is that my location indeed bounces around by a few meters even though I am not moving. Needless to say, this sucks :)

My refresh occurs every 10 seconds. Unfortunately the threshold speed I want to detect is below the "spurious" speed that I am getting from the OS so I am looking for another way (other than speed itself) to gauge whether the OS is feeding me crap data.

Comment: I don't think the OS is feeding you crap data.  I think the variance you're seeing is just the way that civilian GPS operates -- it simply isn't as accurate as military GPS.  Civilian grade GPS, IIRC, also changes the granularity of its reading in order to deliberately induce inaccuracies.  The only suggestion I have is to make sure Assisted GPS is enabled on your device, which might bring your readings into an acceptable range.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in doors, how does GPS even work?  If it can hit some satellites, you might get decent data, if not, you are detecting proximity with respect to wifi hotspots and that is very problematic.  You will likely need to build in some logic to detect consistency of movement that would be consistent with being in a car.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2056266/793607) that goes into more details.

Comment: I found out that the accuracy jumps from <=48m to >=128m when indoors which allows me to disregard data under these circumstances. Unfortunately that also means that when accuracy is reduced outdoors driving around, that data will be disregarded too. I get an accuracy of 12-48m walking around in Tokyo. Can I expect similar accuracy in most major cities when driving?

Comment: PS: errata, this method is not going to work, accuracy goes down to 100m-200m when actually moving on a vehicle, with GPS connection every 10s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sensor TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and if it is not available use TYPE_ACCELEROMETER with a low pass filter to filter out gravity and get the device acceleration. You can use those alone or in conjunction with Location. More info at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ACCELEROMETER

Comment: I have another problem, indoors the 10000 ms interval GPS scanning turns into an on-going blinking of the icon on top which presumably indicates that because a fix can't be acquired the device is never giving up and keeps using electricity to scan... is it possible to set a real timeout where the device gives up and starts scanning if a fix isn't achieved within a few seconds?

Comment: You can start a countdown timer when calling requestUpdate and in onFinish of the timer call removeUpdates and start another timer to start requestUpdate onFinish(). In onLocationChanged cancel the first timer and restart again. So the first timer would be cancel and restart if the fix occurs before the time expires otherwise, it is cancel and the second timer is started and after the set time expires will request update again.