# How to use Cordova Geolocation plugin in offline mode

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gps, ngcordova, android-gps

I'm using `ngCordova` Geolocation plugin in my ionic1 app. It gives me latitude and longitude only when I'm connected to wifi or mobile data. How can I do this work offline?

The error message for offline mode:

```
Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received
```

**NOTE:** I searched and someone has said that I must use this option:

```
enableHighAccuracy: true
```

But no diffrenece.

**EDIT:** I found out it works somehow in real device. But not always. It's searching for gps but just sometimes it can find. Any idea?

Comment: maybe the gps takes too long to find the position and you get a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost found the problem. I must test the `Geolocation` plugin out of a department, otherwise the **gps** can not find my location.

Inside department, it can find hardly ever (almost never), but with internet connection. Out of department it works in **offline mode**.

Comment: If "inside department" means "indoors" and "outside department" means "outdoors", then this is to be expected: the GPS signal from satellites is obscured by most solid buildings and hence will not be received indoors - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2056266/777265)

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the default timeout of the plugin:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  maximumAge: 30000
});
```

Comment: My timeout is `10000`.  But let me test yours.

Comment: No! It's just searching for gps, but it can't find. It hardly ever can find the geolocation :(